# MongoDB in Kohana 3

Tags: php, mongodb, kohana, kohana-3

I wrote a Mongo_Model to use inside kohana and felt pretty snappy about it until I tried getting anything working with it. The problem is the Kohana's Model class does many things for me that I don't want it to, such as creating a default database (and thus crashes my app). So how do I go about truly implementing my mongo model in Kohana? How do I disable the default database and Just use my model to handle everything with mongo? or the other way around, how do I change kohana's code to acknowledge me using mongo? I just don't want to stick my fingers where they don't belong (e.g. Kohana's system folder) and I want this to be as clean as possible. Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to extend the Model class from your Mongo_Model class.  The base model class is there in case you wish to use Kohana's database library.

There is a project for Kohana that implements MongoDB: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/mongodb-php-odm

Comment: there is also another project called MangoDB for Kohana but I decided to roll my own. So I should just drop the extend?

Comment: Yeah, if you don't want to use Kohana's library then just drop the extend and you'll be alright.  If you wanted you could overload the default Model class by adding a Model class to your application.  Then you could encapsulate any base functionality common to all your models.

Comment: well, with mongo I just need one model. Talking about schmea-less :-)

Comment: Schema-less is really neat. MangoDB really isn't schema-less (not a bad thing! different wrappers for different scenarios :)) but Colins is.